# Communication between motherboard serial port and usb ftdi chip

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to communicate between a serial port on a motherboard and a usb ftdi chip.

The ftdi chip is plugged into a windows machine and is assigned the label COM3. I used putty to set the baud rate to 115200, 8 bit, no parity, no flow and 1 stop bit:
[image: putty setup]

The serial port on the motherboard has the standard pinout,:

[image: mb serial port]

And I have the grounds connected and the rx/tx connections properly swizzled.

I am running ubuntu server 18.04.2 on the machine with the serial port and I am using tio to setup the serial port:

```
clifford@Ryzen-Server:~$ sudo tio --baudrate 115200 --databits 8 --flow none --stopbits 1 --parity none /dev/ttyS0
```

But all I seem to be able to send/receive is gibberish:

[image: putty output]

[image: tio output]

So I have obviously missed something, but I am not sure what. If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You repeatedly refer to *"a usb ftdi chip."*  That has to be more than just a *"chip"*.  Exactly what is it?  Could it be a USB-to-TTL-serial adapter?  IOW does this *"usb ftdi chip"* have a DB9 connector or flying leads?

Comment: It's a usb to serial chip that has rx/tx/gnd/vcc/dtr/cts/dcd/dsr headers.

Comment: Ah, my problem is my ignorance. rs-232 and generic serial aren't the same thing. I need an additional chip: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/RS232_MAXIM_MAX232CSE-T_MAX232CSE-T_C45119.html